# How to present to a different window using IDXGISwapChain and ID3D11Device/ID3D11DeviceContext?

Tags: graphics, windows-7, direct3d, direct3d11, dxgi

Previously, when I've built tools, I've used D3D version 9, where the call to Present() can take a target window and rectangle, and you can thus draw from a single device into many different windows. This is great when using D3D to accelerate desktop applications, and/or building tools rather than games!

I've also built a game renderer with D3D11 before, which is also great, because the state management and threading interfaces are well designed, and you can even target D3D 9 level hardware that's still pretty common in the wild (as opposed to D3D 10, which can only target 10-and-better).

However, now I want to build a tool with D3D11. Unfortunately, the IDXGISwapChain that comes back from D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain() seems to "remember" its HWND, and only wants to present to that window. This is highly inconvenient, because I may have a large number of windows that each need fairly simple graphics drawn to them, and only in response to a WM_PAINT (again, this is for a tool, not a game).

What I want to do is to save back buffer RAM. Specifically, I used to be able to create a single back buffer, the size of the desktop, that I knew could cover all rendering needs, and then that would be the single copy allocated. Even if there are 10 overlapping windows, they all render through the same back buffer, so there's no waste of memory beyond the initial allocation. I can create textures that are not swap chains, and use them as "render targets," but I can't find a good way of presenting to an arbitrary rectangle of an arbitrary client window, without reading back the bitmap and copying it into a DIBSection, which would be really inefficient. Also, there is no way to create many swap chains, and having them share the same back buffer.

The best I can do is to create one swap chain per window, and resize the back buffer of each swap chain to be really small, except when I render to the swap chain, at which point I resize it to match the window. However, this seems inefficient, because resizing the targets is not a "free" operation AFAICT. So, is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I ended up with was to create one back buffer per separate display area, and not size it to the back buffer. I imagine that, in a world where desktop composition and transparency can happy to "anything" behind my back, that's probably helpful to the system.
Learn to love the VVM system, I guess :-) (VVM for Virtual Video Memory)